# Уместна ли запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая после слова "что-либо" и почему в предложении:

> ...герой рассказа Беликов, живущий со страхом сделать что-либо(,)
> выходящее за рамки приличия, которые...

Answer (score 2):

Правило гласит.

Определительный оборот, стоящий после неопределённого местоимения, обычно не обособляется, так как образует единое целое с предшествующим местоимением: **Её большие глаза… искали в моих что-нибудь похожее на надежду (Л.);**

Но при менее тесной связи слов и при наличии после местоимения паузы оборот обособляется (выделяется запятыми): **И кто-то, вспотевший и задыхающийся, бегает из магазина в магазин (Пан.) — обособлены два одиночных определения.**

[Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)

В вашем примере как раз-таки есть пауза, поэтому запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

У Д.Розенталя есть правило о том, что если причастный оборот стоит после притяжательного, указательного или неопределенного местоимения, то он не отделяется запятой от этого местоимения.